# Get current domain name in an OSGi service component in AEM on activation

Tags: java, service, osgi, aem

I am writing an OSGI service component in AEM.
I want to fetch current domain name in the activate method of the service component.

Currently, I'm writing a construct method, to get request from referring class/service/model/servlet to initialize the 'request' class object and using this request object to get the server name

```
private SlingHttpServletRequest request;
private String domainName;

@Override
public void construct(final SlingHttpServletRequest request) {
    this.request = request;
}

@Override
public void setDomainName(){
     this.domainName = request.getServerName();
}
```

And `this.domainName` is used in multiple service method implementations.

So, I have to call 2 extra service method,

1. Construct - to initialize global `request` object
2. setDomainName - to initialize `domainName` global object to be used across all the other service methods

Is there anyway to get domainName in activate method, so that i do not have to call the above two methods in order to use the service.

Note:- I cannot create an OSGI config for domain name, as this domain name is already being used as **key property** to identify the **OSGI config of a given factory**

Answer (score 2):

Since AEM publish servers might be used for several domains, there is no way to "know" the right domain without getting the request. There might also be some magic being done by the web server and the CDN before the request is even reaching AEM.

On top of that, the activate method is not called each time the service is used, since those components are used multiple times.

So I think no, there is no way to guess what the domain of the next incoming request will be when the component is activated.

BR,
Oliver

Answer (score 0):

To add to @OliverGeberts answer, this information can be added to the content (i.e. page properties of the language root) or some sort of tenant configuration.